# Toilet cistern besides the toilet

Tags: plumbing, toilet, cistern

I am wondering if it is possible to install a built in cistern next to the toilet. Please see the image attached - the idea is to have a cistern in the short dividing wall next to the toilet bowl. Cistern would be installed in the right angle to the toilet. I am not worried about the gravity drop, as the wall could be slightly taller than what is on the image attached.[image]

Comment: For what purpose? Are you actually collecting rainwater?

Comment: And the answer is "yes". Did you have a more specific question?

Comment: If you're just trying to get the bowl closer to the wall, consider an in-wall toilet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly do it with a separate tank toilet and some inventive plumbing, but the flush performance is going to be worse than a close-coupled toilet, especially modern low flush capacity toilets that have a large flush valve that discharges the water very quickly.

[image]

Comment: This was my first thought, but I'm not sure if you can buy them anywhere these days.  I think you're right that a longer pipe might reduce performance.

Comment: They're only found at specialist renovators' supply places, so they're many times the price of a normal toilet.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you know if the length of the initial vertical pipe as seen on your photo would help with the flush?

Comment: *Probably not. Very old* toilets had wall-mounted cisterns quite high up, and were waterhogs with dubious flush performance despite being waterhogs. Modern properly designed low-flush toilets (not the early examples where the bugs hadn't been worked out of the designs) do a very good job of flushing with greatly reduced amounts of water and no great elevation. If you are *really* looking for a "tankless" design visually, you might look into commercial "pressure flush" toilets, though you may need a local pressure tank and some large plumbing to support those in a typical residence.

Answer (score 1):

If you step back from "cistern" you've no doubt encountered "tankess" pressure-flush toilet at most public restrooms, either with a pipe like this, or with a button on the wall and less visible/exposed piping:

[image]

In a typical house, you'll need a very local pressure tank and some large supply pipe between to support these things, which are designed for buildings with a much more robust water supply.